# Xamarin.Android loading Syncfusion Charts inside Fragments: need bounds Rect

Tags: android, xamarin, charts, fragment, syncfusion

I'm facing a problem using **Syncfusion** Charts (Com.Syncfusion.Charts) in an **Android** Project. I'm using BottomNavigationView and loading content into Fragments.

This specific fragment has 6 views organized with 2 views side by side, 4 of them containing charts and the others have textviews.

The fragment is loading normally (sometimes). But it crashes when I navigate through others fragments or activities and return to the charts fragment.

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Java.Lang.NullPointerException: need bounds Rect
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <e499a5498b1b48379b88fe5ed629079f>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in <e499a5498b1b48379b88fe5ed629079f>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.Graphics.Paint.GetTextBounds (System.String text, System.Int32 start, System.Int32 end, Android.Graphics.Rect bounds) [0x00079] in <85286732fd894fbbba95d2215e5f9ec6>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Com.Syncfusion.Charts.ChartLabelStyle.measureLabel (System.String label, Android.Graphics.Rect labelRect, Android.Graphics.Paint paintText, System.Single leftMargin, System.Single topMargin, System.Single rightMargin, System.Single bottomMargin) [0x00027] in <a9b0cef031b54405bf316434aa63799b>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Com.Syncfusion.Charts.ChartLabelStyle.MeasureLabel (System.String label) [0x0003e] in <a9b0cef031b54405bf316434aa63799b>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Com.Syncfusion.Charts.XyDataSeries.CalculateDataMarkerLabelPoint (Com.Syncfusion.Charts.DataMarkerLabel dataMarkerLabel, System.Drawing.PointF labelPoint, Com.Syncfusion.Charts.ChartDataMarkerLabelStyle labelStyle, System.Boolean isDrawLine) [0x00011] in <a9b0cef031b54405bf316434aa63799b>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Com.Syncfusion.Charts.XyDataSeries.CreateDataMarkerLabels () [0x00198] in <a9b0cef031b54405bf316434aa63799b>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Com.Syncfusion.Charts.ChartBase.UpdateArea () [0x00131] in <a9b0cef031b54405bf316434aa63799b>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Com.Syncfusion.Charts.ChartBase.OnMeasureChart () [0x00031] in <a9b0cef031b54405bf316434aa63799b>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Com.Syncfusion.Charts.SfChart.OnMeasure (System.Int32 widthMeasureSpec, System.Int32 heightMeasureSpec) [0x0003e] in <a9b0cef031b54405bf316434aa63799b>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Android.Views.View.n_OnMeasure_II (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Int32 widthMeasureSpec, System.Int32 heightMeasureSpec) [0x00008] in <85286732fd894fbbba95d2215e5f9ec6>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:a6e2f256-5633-444e-9d6a-06be6e391800 (intptr,intptr,int,int)
[MonoDroid]   --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
[MonoDroid] java.lang.NullPointerException: need bounds Rect
[MonoDroid]     at android.graphics.Paint.getTextBounds(Paint.java:2192)
[MonoDroid]     at md51e14154f795d24977fc65ef53030a808.SfChart.n_onMeasure(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at md51e14154f795d24977fc65ef53030a808.SfChart.onMeasure(SfChart.java:53)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:697)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1260)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:337)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:697)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:697)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:481)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
[MonoDroid]     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
[MonoDroid]     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
[MonoDroid]     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
[MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
[MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: I'm doing some tests and, actually, I think is the graph insertion inside a RelativeLayout. So, it was being inserted without RelativeLayout properties. I've started to change the logic for using LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout. Tomorrow I should have a definitive opinion about it.

Comment: Have you solved your problem ?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT No :/ It's something wrong with Syncfusion Charts when labels or legends are activated. SFCharts sometimes can't calculate the size of these properties and crash the app. So, I inserted a Layout to implement a legend manually.

Comment: @WagnerSilva Seems, the Syncfusion Chart is working properly inside the fragment. I have also created a sample with fragment and loaded Chart inside that, its working properly. I suspect that there is some mismatch between your layout hierarchy and mine. If possible, could you please take a look into this simple sample and let me know if you are able figure the difference in Chart configuration. https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvh7mmkfhmn55sj/ChartSample.zip?dl=0

Comment: Hi, @Prabakaran! Thank you for the example! It helped us to focus on some questions about async methods and data processing. So, we moved the code that get data from our server in an activity before handling with fragments. Also, we moved the all the processing data to that activity. So, the fragment now is only responsible for add the pre-processed graph, and the crash stopped occurring.

Answer (score 0):

[Solved]

The crash was throwing because parallel layout processing. So, the problem was occurring eventually. We refactored some stuff and let the fragment only responsible for loading the graphs.

**1. Async Data**: We moved all the communication with the API to an activity before handling with the fragments.

**2. Data Processing**: After getting the data from the API, we process the datamodels and save the graphs for future use using singleton pattern.